# How to configure GCP cluster for dask-workers in another region than scheduler was started

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I have one kubernetes cluster in region us-east1 where dask-scheduler was started and i want to start another cluster in region us-west1 where would like run dask-workers. As I understand connection between scheduler and workers is bidirectional, so I can't expose scheduler with external IP, I also have to expose workers too. Maybe there is exists some way to avoid this problem and don't expose each worker or somehow possible to configure network for two clusters in different regions and have ability to communicate between them

Answer (score 1):

I recommend running the dask workers and scheduler in the same region, and ideally fairly close to each other in the network.

If you have to have a distant connection then the place to do this is between the Client and Scheduler.  This blogpost might be helpful: https://words.yuvi.in/post/dask-local-kubernetes/